# How to change the progress bar colors based on the value

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using html5 progress bar here I want to implement different colors for progress bar based on the values
like if value>80% then progress bar color should be red
if bellow that color should be green for this I implemented jQuery function but it's not working for me

Previously I used html5 meter tag. It's sure that this element won't be support in IE10/11 (not visible) after doing some research on that it's get to know.
Instead of meter tag I used Progress Bar this is visible  in all the browsers means it's supporting for IE also but here there is one more bug like for this colors getting changing.
Ex. In IE Background color is 'blue' for Firefox it's 'Green' and for Chrome it's some different color.
At development point of view we are giving some background color but it's displaying various colors in different browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var item = $('#progress_bar').val();
        if (item != null) {
            if (value) >= 900) { $('#progress_bar').css({background:'red'}); }
            else {$('#progress_bar').css({ background:'green'});}}
        }
     );
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var item = $('#progress_bar').val();
if (item != null){
if (value) >= 900) {$('#progress_bar').css({background:'red'});}
else {$('#progress_bar').css({ background:'green'});}}
});
</script>

Comment: Please update the question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Where you do get the value from?

Comment: Each browser handles this a bit differently. Please read interesting article on http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/
You need to add your own style to force same style depending of browser used.

Comment: Can you provide a [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)?

Comment: These values I am getting from controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/55HtU/19/)

You have to use pseudo class selector and set your color in it.
Please note IE use color, and chrome / firefox use background-color.

[image]

A CSS Code example with 2 values such as progress = 10 and progress = 20:

```
progress{
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;

  /* Get rid of default border in Firefox. */
  border: none;

  /* Dimensions */
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;    
}

.progress-10 {
  color: green; 
}

.progress-10::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color:green;
}

.progress-10::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color:green;
}

.progress-20 {
  color: red; 
}

.progress-20::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color:red;
}

.progress-20::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Part of style I used comes from http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/